# Python outputs "None" when I try to copies the lines of text from the input file to the output file, numbering each line as it goes

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to read `fileA` and write the contents of `fileA` to `fileB` while having the line numbers right-justified in 4 columns, but I keep getting "none" output.

```py
fileA = input("Enter the filename 1: ")
fileB = input("Enter the filename 2: ")
lineNo = 0
f = open(fileA, 'r')
g = open(fileB, 'w')
for line in f:
    lineNo += 1
    h = print(lineNo,">", line)
    j = str(h).rjust(4, " ")
g.write(str(j))
```

Comment: Could you comment on what you expect `h = print(lineNo,">", line)` to do? `print` always returns `None`

Comment: `print` constructs a string (sort of) from its arguments as a *side effect* of writing to a file. It does not return the string so constructed. You probably want something like `h = f'{lineNo} > {line}'`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try to think carefully about the logic of the code. First: What should `h` contain, each time through the loop? What do you expect `print(lineNo,">", line)` to do? What do you expect it to *evaluate to*? Therefore, what will `h` actually contain? What is the goal of this `print` call? If it is to create a string, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for [ways to do that](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+assemble+string)? Second: think carefully about `g.write(str(j))`. Should it happen many times, or just once? Do you see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There were a few bugs, but as pointed out, the print statement was causing the most problem.  Here is a debugged version:

```
fileA = input("Enter the filename 1: ")    
fileB = input("Enter the filename 2: ")
lineNo = 0
f = open(fileA, 'r')
g = open(fileB, 'w')
for line in f:
    lineNo += 1
    h = str(lineNo).rjust(4) + ">" + line
    g.write(h)
```

Comment: could get rid of that for-loop entirely and just have... `g.writelines(f'{n:>4}>{line}' for n, line in enumerate(f, start=1))`

Comment: (plus better practice to use `with`... eg: `with open(fileA) as f, open(fileB, 'w') as g:`...

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for finding a good use case for `.writelines`. It never seems to be useful for me personally.

Answer (score 0):

`print` can write to a file as well as the console with a `file=g` parameter, but you'll find that `print` also adds a newline while `line` already has one in the string.  Use `end=''` to supress the extra line number.

`enumerate` is a nice function for numbering what is being iterated over.  It defaults numbering from zero, but adding `start=1` will number from one.

Use `with` statements to make sure your files are closed.  Without closing the file, it might not be flushed to disk when running your code in some IDEs.

Example:

```py
fileA = input("Enter the filename 1: ")
fileB = input("Enter the filename 2: ")
with open(fileA, 'r') as f, open(fileB, 'w') as g:
    for lineNo,line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        print(f"{lineNo:>4}> {line}", end='', file=g)
```